# Returning reverse of a generator using yield keyword

Tags: python

I have function where I have to reverse the list. 
Is it possible rewrite this function to return generators using yield? without storing deltas in a list?

```
def back_propogation(self,activations,output):
    error = output - activations[-1]
    deltas = [error * math_utils.sigmoid_prime(activations[-1])]
    for l in range(len(activations) - 2, 0, -1): 
        deltas.append(deltas[-1].dot(self.weights[l].T)*self.some_function(activations[l]))
    deltas.reverse()
    return deltas
```

Comment: No, you cannot reverse a generator which is the only alternative if you don't want all the data in memory at once,  what does `error * math_utils.sigmoid_prime(activations[-1])` do? Also what is `a`?

Comment: If the next value cannot be calculated given the current value, it is impossible to reverse a generator without storing the list first.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `yield` out the items in the reversed list:

```
for item in reversed(deltas):
    yield item
```

Comment: That once again requires storing in a list.. Once again iterating over the list in reversed order. My question is how to return it in some other way so that I can yield it directly

Comment: Edit your question to include the requirement of not storing the list. Unfortunately you are calculating each delta based on the previous one when you have `delta[-1]` so I'm not sure if you can reverse it without actually storing the list. Given it's a back-propogation algorithm if I recall correctly that means the problem intrinsically needs to be that way as it needs to use the previous information.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in xrange(len(deltas) - 1, -1, -1):
    yield deltas[i]
```

this, at least, saves you the reversing of the list.

Comment: I want it to be in reverse order

Comment: I see, the next delta depends on the predecessor in the original order. Then, of course, if you have already compiled the list, a generator is not very benficial. But you can save the reverse() call, by iterating backwards and yielding

Comment: you are reinventing `reversed`